# Querying information related to another table

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables - Utilizadores and Competencias.

NOTE: Utilizadores = Users And Competencias = Skills

Each user can have 1 or more Skills.

I need to print them in a dropdown menu, where, for each skill, it shows the user that has that skill.

So, SKILLS->USER THAT HAS THE SKILL
(The visual is all done, but it doesn't work properly - Explained next)

Here is the first query:

```
$query2 = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT competencias, id_user FROM ce");
$ut = array();
while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($query2)) $ut[] = $result;
foreach ($ut as $u){
    $id_user=$u[1];
}
```

(Nevermind the number 2 on the query2.)
This query searches in the table "Skills" the id of the user that contains that specific skill. Again, A user can have more than just 1 skill.

Second Query:

```
$query3 = mysql_query("SELECT `id`, `nome` FROM utilizadores WHERE id='$id_user'");
$utt = array();
while ($result2 = mysql_fetch_array($query3)) $utt[] = $result2;
foreach ($utt as $utilizador){
    $nomeuser=$utilizador[1];
}
```

This Second Query searched on the table "Users" for the names of the users

Anf finaly, the third part:

```
foreach ($ut as $hu){
echo "<li class='has-sub'><a><span>" .$hu[0]. "</span></a>";
    echo "<ul><a href='php/curriculo.php?nomeut=$nomeuser'>". $nomeuser. "</a></ul>";
}
```

Now the problem I'm Having:
When the mouse overs the skill present on the dropdown menu, it shows a sub-dropdown showing only the name of the user that contains the skill. But it always shows me the same name.

In the database, Several Skills belong to Several Users, but, on the sub-dropdown, it shows the name of ONE person only, instead of the ones corresponding to their skill.

Let's say:
John has a skill "Sharepoint"
Smith has a skill "Whatever"

When i pass the mouse on "Sharepoint" ->John
When i pass the mouse on "Whatever" -> John - When it really corresponds to "Smith".

I am sorry for the realy long problem, and for my awful english.

Any help is appreciated
Thanks :)

Comment: Quick hint: Just use english words in your examples. More people will be able to help you if you write your examples in a language all users try to speak (i am not a native english speaker myself). And reading a translation for your examples first is kind of offputting :-/

Comment: While the answer provided is not that bad, what you really should do is read up on tutorials on how to work with PHP and MySQL. This is very basic stuff and going thru a few tutorials will improve your skills and you will have to ask fewer questions and have less struggles with your tasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it isn't completely clear to me what info you want from your database, I'll describe you some options. You can process the results with you PHP code. If you need more, just comment and I'll update my answer.

Let say that you got your tables populated like this:

```
users
user_id | username
1       | John
2       | Matt
3       | Rob

skills
user_id | skill
1       | PHP
1       | SQL
1       | HTML
2       | PHP
4       | HTML
```

When using a `left join`, all the rows of the left table will be returned. If there is no match in the right table, it will return NULL. This query

```
SELECT u.username, s.skill 
FROM users AS u 
LEFT JOIN skills as s
ON u.user_id=s.user_id
```

Will return:

```
John    PHP
John    SQL
John    HTML
Matt    PHP
Rob     NULL
```

Using a `right join`, will return all the rows from the right table, giving a NULL if there is no match in the left table

```
SELECT u.username, s.skill
FROM users AS u
RIGHT JOIN skills AS s 
ON u.user_id = s.user_id
```

Will return:

```
John    PHP
John    SQL
John    HTML
Matt    PHP
NULL    HTML
```

Using the `inner join`, all rows that match in both tables will return. So this query

```
SELECT u.username, s.skill
FROM users AS u
RIGHT JOIN skills AS s 
ON u.user_id = s.user_id
```

will return

```
John    PHP
John    SQL
John    HTML
Matt    PHP
```

Comment: *Since it isn't completely clear to me what info you want from your database* - :D

Comment: Okay, it is working now. Thank you very much for your answer. It was realy helpful ^^

Answer (score 0):

In your second query's foreach statement, it appears that you're simply assigning to $nomeuser whatever was the last name that was retrieved from the second query. That is why you just have the single value for $nomeuser.

To fix, I would first make only one SQL call by using a JOIN:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.competencias, a.id_user, b.nome
FROM ce a
JOIN utilizadores b ON a.id_user = b.id
```

Then, you could store the results in an associative array, where the key of the associative array is the competency and the value is an array containing the names of all people who share that competency. WARNING: this is problematic because more than one user may share the same name. In your third snippet of code it appears you link to user profiles (php/curriculo.php?nomeut=$nomeuser) by using the name of the user. It would be much better to use a unique user ID. It's possible that $nomeuser may refer to a unique username, in which case this isn't a concern, but in your example you presented common names like 'John' and 'Smith', which is why I am concerned.

But that aside, assuming you've stored the query results in an associative array (with key as the competency and value as a unique user identifier), you could then loop over the array and extract the necessary values to output the list you want.

Here is an example of a multi-dimensional associative array:

```
$myArray = array(
    "Sharepoint" => array("John", "Lisa", "Tim"),
    "Excel" => array("Jim", "Nick", "Sam"),
    "PowerPoint" => array("Sally", "Mary")
);
```

You can read more about these types of arrays in the PHP doc: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: Thansk for you answer, but i changed the query using a JOIN, and it is working. THanks anyway

Comment: You are very welcome. As I mentioned, the other thing you should be concerned of is using nome from the utilizadores table to identify users if nome is not unique. (You appear to identify the user by nome when you link to the curriculo.php page.) If nome is unique, then it's no concern.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'm going to do that :)